# How can I get the fields in v2 I was able to receive upon a request in v1?

Tags: linkedin-api

The fields I was able to receive in v1 Linkedin Api such as positions with r_basicprofile permission, are no longer returned from request. I understand that some of the fields are deprecated, however there is no detailed documentation on the objects that substitute these fields. As stated in the documentation below, positions field is deprecated but there is another object like positions that should be returned from request. The documentation fails to provide any more details on positions. #LinkedIn

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile

You can find a code snippet below.

```py
data = None
params = {'oauth2_access_token': token}
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection (id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture,positions)'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','X-RestLi-Protocol-Version':'2.0.0'}
kw = dict(data=data, params=params,headers=headers, timeout=60)
response = requests.request("GET", url, **kw)
status_code = response.status_code
#content = json.loads(response.content)
return response.content
```

## LinkedIn

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the migration from `r_basicprofile` to `r_liteprofile` in your App.  Check it out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq

I believe the url query you have is correct, but here is documentation on (for example) Profile Picture fields & a sample response:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/profile-picture?context=linkedin/consumer/context

There have been tons of changes to LinkedIn API lately.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestions. I already go through all of the documentation. But as I explained, there are fields that do not have enough documentation. Profile picture is well documented. But position field for example is not. You can check it out from the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/position?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: Ah, yes, no specific examples for "positions"...and they previously stated under Permissions that it was deprecated...so not sure why they said it's deprecated but then provide documentation on parameters?  So you may not be able to get "positions" but you can get your current "title": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/member-rich-media-api

Comment: Also, I believe you would need "r_fullprofile" and field name "summaryRichMediaAssociations" to get the title information of your profile.  And here's some more details/examples for other profile items:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context